# Collecting Java heapdump under load

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running load against Tomcat 6 running on Java 6. I want to collect a heapdump of the Java heap while the Tomcat server is under load. I normally use jmap -dump to collect my heapdumps.

However, when I try to do this when Tomcat is handling a high load I find that the heapdump collection fails.

Is jmap the best tool for collecting a heap dump from a process under load? What are the possible causes which would cause jmap to fail to collect a heapdump?

If jmap is not the best tool - what is better?

It is entirely acceptable to me for jmap (or some other tool) to stop the world within the Java process while the heap dump is taken.

Comment: Have you tried to attach VisualVM to the VM and create a HeapDump using that?

Comment: This isn't ideal for me as my Tomcat is running on a remote Linux server. VisualVM includes support for remote heap dumps but this requires that a JMX port be opened when the JVM is started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235802/ways-how-to-get-heap-dump-from-running-tomcat-7 has more detailed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that running Tomcat with a JMX port allows me to take a remote heapdump using visualvm. This succeeded for me when jmap failed.

Answer (score 2):

*Is jmap the best tool for collecting a heap dump from a process under load?*

I think: No it isn't. [From this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html):

> NOTE - This utility is unsupported and
>   may or may not be available in future
>   versions of the JDK.

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: No, i never needed to deal with heap dumps, but I looked for jmap info, just curious, get luck.

Answer (score 2):

I've also found jmap can pretty temperamental. If you're having problems:

- Try it again. It often manages to get a heap dump after a couple of attempts if it first fails
- Use the -F option
- Add -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError as a standard configuration to proactively take heap dumps when an OOM error is thrown
- Run Tomcat interactively and add the heap dump on ctrl-break option. This gives you a thread dump too, something you'll probably need anyway
- If your heap size is especially large and you have a repeatable condition, temporarily lower your heap size. It makes the resulting file much easier to handle, takes less time and is more likely to succeed

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I'll try retrying jmap next time. I have posted my own answer about using visualvm.