# ways how to get heap dump from running tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7, heap-dump

I've tried this [Get a heapdump on JVM from Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578710/get-a-heapdump-on-jvm-from-tomcat-6)
but it doesn't work for me, Is there other ways to get heap dump from tomcat server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem did you meet trying to make the heap dump?

Comment: You link just make heap dump when JVM dead because of out of memory. It is not allowing you to make heapdump, whenever you want. But it is still very useful option for you.

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way to get heap dump is to use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html). On the machine with java process execute jmap command. Example of usage:

```
jmap -dump:file=/mnt/heapdump_2013-04-01.data 29842
```

use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) to know java Pid.

---

Also you can make heap dump via [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). You can connect to the remote machine via [jmx](https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html) or [jstatd](http://www.first8.nl/profiling-remote-jvm-using-visualvm/). You can make heapdump and store on the remote machine.

To analyze heapdumps can advice you: [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Very powerful tool which allow you to quickly understand problems. You can find [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/08/create-and-understand-java-heapdumps-act-4/) good inro to the MAT.

---

If you don't want to stop application for a long time you can make binary dump([You can use gcore or gdb](https://superuser.com/questions/401182/how-can-i-create-a-dump-file-of-a-running-process-in-linux)). And you can [use jmap to analyze gdb dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951095/tool-for-analyzing-java-core-dump). More information you can read on the [atlassian blog](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/so-you-want-your-jvms-heap/). Beware of [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981080/core-dump-taken-with-gcore-jmap-conversion-to-hprof-file-format-fails-with-erro) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934547/how-to-reliably-take-jvm-core-dump-if-application-is-in-gc).

Comment: You may have to use "sudo"

Answer (score 5):

Another way besides the "Dump heap"-Button of jvisualvm is via the JMX-interface. This way even allows you to specify where to store the dump.

connect to tomcat's JMX-server using jconsole or jvisualvm with JMX-plugin. Then got to `com.sun.management` -> `HotSpotDiagnotic` -> `Operations`. Next to `dumpHeap` fill in the two parameters. From oracle's documentation (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html)):

> Parameters:
>
> outputFile - the system-dependent filename
>
> live - if true dump only live objects i.e. objects that are reachable from others

Then press `dumpHeap` and watch the VM freeze for some time while writing the dump.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend visual VM http://visualvm.java.net/ It is a all in one tool which can connect to tomcat, create and read heap dump, creates thread dump, cpu and memory sampler.

If you use new jdk 1.7, VisualVM is already packaged in your jdk folder.